# Constraint SQL on column password

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner in SQL and I want to do something on my table 'User'.

I would like to make a constraint on my 'Password' column. The constraint is "Passwords only can be made of letters and digits, the only symbol allowed is "_" "

I don't know how to allowed only one symbol with a check() constraint.

I searched a lot on google and didn't find the solution.

I was thinking something like this :

CONSTRAINT TABLE_PASSWORD check ( password ........ )

Comment: Is this for a school project or other learning exercise? For a real application, you shouldn't be storing raw passwords in the DB (only a hash of the password).

Comment: Thank's for your answer, it is only for a school project no need to secure passwords, its only about making constraint on Strings

Comment: Which DBMS is this? (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL)

Comment: Im using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple REGEXP would be enough.
Below query only allows digits , letters and `_` symbol:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    id int ,
    `password` varchar(25) CONSTRAINT TABLE_PASSWORD  CHECK (`password` REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*$') );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/X05evHMm

*Note*. Use plain text passwords only for testing purposes

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, real applications should not store raw passwords in the DB. But since you have clarified this is for a school project, I hope this helps you:

As you said, you can use a [`CHECK` constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html). You will likely want to use it in combination with [`REGEXP` or `NOT REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html).

Probably something like:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint CHECK (mycolumn NOT REGEXP '[^A-Z0-9_]')
```

You can see it working [in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-qYnewCy).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I didnt know REGEXP its perfect for my problem.